# How to check the validity of a password (input from users) without using import re?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to check the validity of a password without using `import re`, but it always gives me not valid. Where is my error, please?

```
password = input('Enter your password: ')

while True:
    if password not in [i for i in range(0,9)]:
        print('not valid')
        break
    elif (len(password)<6 or len(password)> 9):
        print('not valid')
        break
    elif password not in [chr(c) for c in range(97, 123)]:
        print('not valid')
        break
    elif password not in [chr(c) for c in range(65, 91)]:
        print('not valid')
        break
    elif password not in ('$','#','@'):
        print('Not valid')
        break
    else:
        print('Valid')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first test always triggers `True`. `password` is a string and so it is not inside that list of numbers.

Making the list items strings fixes it:

```
if password not in [str(i) for i in range(0,9)]:
```

but only for single digit passwords (!).

I presume you'd want to test each separate *character* instead:

```
for ch in password:
    .. your tests
```

but you have to re-think your algorithm, because if a character is `x` it immediately fails the first test. What you have is a sequence of

```
not(a) or not(b) or not(c)
```

and you want either

```
not(a) and not(b) and not(c)
```

or

```
not (a or b or c)
```